# What software should use on Windows for backup?

Tags: windows, backup

Earlier i used Cobian Backup, but this software have some problems: long time not supported; not open-source; have functional for remote control another cobian but in fact its not working; not all mail servers can work with cobian maybe because of SSL updating.
Requirement that i want from software: open-source or at least freeware, modern to our days updates, GUI, CLI, scheduler, archiving, compress, encryption, send to local or network storage, send to FTP, mail notification, service start, remote control, VSS necessarily support.
I found today "duplicati" and it seems that most of my request can handle, but the version in beta-development and i not testing in full mode yet. Exist the software for this requirement for today? Give me advice please.

Comment: Your question reads like you already have a specific piece of software in front of you and you are just listing its specs, so that the answer will end up being exactly that software. Because I can't think of another explanation for a laundry list of random features that aren't likely to be ever needed together.

Comment: I dont have software that do all jobs for my requirements. I know a lot software but i cant find software that do it correct and like combine-software.